# Не срабатывает http запрос , https работает стабильно

Tags: java, android

mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.vkinfo;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import static com.example.vkinfo.Utils.NetworkUtils.generateURL;
import static com.example.vkinfo.Utils.NetworkUtils.getResponseFromURL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText searchField;
    private Button searchButton;
    private TextView result;

    class VKQueryTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            String response = null;
            try {
                response = getResponseFromURL(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            result.setText(response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchField = findViewById(R.id.et_search_field);
        searchButton = findViewById(R.id.b_seach_VK);
        result = findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                URL generatedURL = generateURL(searchField.getText().toString());
                new VKQueryTask().execute(generatedURL);
            }


        };

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }
}
```

class NetworkUtils

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NetworkUtils {
// если меняешь ссылку на http не срабатывает :((((
    private static final String VK_API_BASE_URL = "https://site.com"; 
    private static  final String VK_USERS_GET = "/android/check.php";
    private static final String PARAM_USER_ID = "tel";


    public static URL generateURL(String userId){
        Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(VK_API_BASE_URL + VK_USERS_GET)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_USER_ID, userId)                    
                .build();
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return url;
    }

    public static String getResponseFromURL(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

            boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();

            if (hasInput) {
                return scanner.next();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

    }

}
```

манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vkinfo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Ошибку приведите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не привели лог ошибки, засим мой ответ - лишь предположение.

И заключается оно в том, что вы тестируете на ОС версии 9+. На ней, согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902630/3212712) надо в манифест, в тэг `application` добавить явное разрешение на незащищённые соединения:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!!!